# Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/scene/control/ButtonBar

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, classnotfoundexception, controlsfx

I am new to JavaFx and I learned that I could create notifications using controlsfx . However, after including the package and running the notification code I get a class not found exception and I don't have any idea how to tackle it since I have not gotten any help on the web upon research. I am using JDK jdk1.8.0_20, Netbeans 8.0.2 and controlsfx 8.40.14. Below is my code for creating notification

```
Platform.runLater(() -> { 
    Notifications notifications = Notifications.create().title("Verification successful").text("User has been verified").graphic(null).hideAfter(Duration.seconds(2)).position(Pos.TOP_RIGHT);
                                                                    notifications.show();
});
```

This is the exception

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/scene/control/ButtonBar
    at org.controlsfx.control.Notifications$NotificationPopupHandler.show(Notifications.java:349)
    at org.controlsfx.control.Notifications$NotificationPopupHandler.show(Notifications.java:322)
    at org.controlsfx.control.Notifications.show(Notifications.java:269)
    at flock.express.VerificationController.lambda$ProcessCaptureResult$0(VerificationController.java:263)
    at flock.express.VerificationController$$Lambda$304/1685872131.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/873652227.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/501263526.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/96639997.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: jdk1.8.0_20 is quite old, may you try with the latest jdk8? ( Java SE 8u181)

Comment: @pdem I tried to update my Java but the system keeps telling me my Java is up-to-date when I went ahead to download jdk 10 it didn't work with my IDE. I would be glad if you could recommend a jdk version for me

Comment: as ButtonBar is supported from Java8u40 , make sure your IDE is referring to your proper jdk

Comment: Thank you both. I downloaded jdk1.8.0_181 and configured my IDE to use it and it works fine now. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded jdk1.8.0_181 and since I am using Netbeans I changed netbeans_jdkhome in Netbeans.conf file to use it and it works fine now